# .NET updates on Postgresql Windows hosts

Tags: postgresql, redis

I Started managing postgresql and redis recently. I have a postgresql Db cluster and redis installed in windows server 2019. I would like to know if postgresql and redis has dependencies with .NET framework.

1. Is there any .NET framework prerequisite to install postgres 14 in windows 2019?
2. If there are no dependencies between .NET framework and postgresql, I would allow .NET updates to get applied automatically along with monthly OS patches.

I am from SQL Server background. MSSQL and .NET have tight dependencies, so I won't allow automatic .NET patches unless and until I verify those patches in a lower environment and make sure there are no breaking changes.

I would like to know the same for Postgres and redis. I could not see it in the software requirements in the product documentation, hence seeking help from community.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL itself is totally unrelated to .NET. If you use a .NET provider for PostgreSQL, such as Npgsql, that does of course depend on .NET.

Comment: Thank you @Laurenz Albe . Does redis has any dependency?

Comment: I have no idea about Redis, but since it runs on normal operating systems, it probably has no dependency to .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Redis and PostgreSQL servers does not have any .NET dependencies. Clients (applications) can have some.

Redis is not officialy available for Windows, you can install linux version via WSL so there are no .NET dependencies. Requirements for installing WSL mentions only version of Windows so there should be no dependency on .NET.

It's long time since I worked with PostgeSQL, but according to its documentation you can build it from source using GCC for Linux without installing any .NET. Windows version is built from the same source.